# How do I enable a service broker queue when it is disabled?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I have a scenario where an external application is monitoring a queue and then taking an action when something is put into the queue. I just wrapped this to happen inside of a transaction to try to prevent things from getting out of the queue if the action has failed. What is happening is that under certain conditions the queue will get disabled if I have a failure in my application that causes the transaction to rollback.

What I'm looking for is a way to enable the queue without opening up SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 3):

The poison message detection will kick in if 5 consecutive RECEIVE statements are rolled back. there is no way to disble this, nor there is any way to re-enable the queue in the queue reader. Because the disabling is asynchronous, it can disable the queue *after* your logic tries to re-enable a disabled queue.

The proper solution is never to rollback intentionally and handle all errors. However, this [isn't always possible](http://rusanu.com/2008/08/13/error-handling-and-activation/). My recommendation would be to hook up an [event notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453.aspx) on the queue for the QUEUE_DISABLED event. This will fire a notification and you can react to this notification.

Queues can be re-enabled with:

```
ALTER QUEUE [queuename] WITH STATUS = ON;
```

Comment: When I manually disable the service through SQL Server Management Studio and run the ALTER QUEUE command it does not appear as re-enabled. Or am I just not being patient enough and waiting long enough?

Comment: I assume that by disable service in SSMS you mean disable the queue. SSMS doe snot refresh itself if you update metadata in a query windows, you need to hit F5 in the object explorer to force it to refresh.

Comment: @RemusRusanu It has been a long time passed, I am in the exact situation right now and I wonder if the behaviour is still same?

Comment: @ibubi is the same